# How to get session value in frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, sessions

I have set a session value in admin by below code

```
Mage::getModel('core/session')->setAutoWebsiteId(1);
```

But when I get this session value in frontend by code below it returns nothing.

```
Mage::getModel('core/session')->getAutoWebsiteId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not sure if it is feasible to do this way since magento frontend and admin are separate.

However, Alan has wrote one nice extension for us.

https://github.com/astorm/Magento_CrossAreaSessions

**USAGES**

```
$adminhtml  = Mage::getModel('pulsestorm_crossareasession/manager')
->getSessionData('adminhtml'); 

$frontend   = Mage::getModel('pulsestorm_crossareasession/manager')
->getSessionData('frontend');
```

Comment: I have an install with 2 domains. Both live on the same codebase, just in different folders. Admin lives on domain 1, but I want to use this plugin on domain 2. When I vardump adminhtml it comes up empty. Any ideas on how to achieve this?